# Mono didn't find UIA Bridge, but the packages are already installed

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, uia

i was searching for a long time now but cant find a solution for my problem:

i compiled a c# project successfull (with monodevelop)

and when i try to run it with >mono fubar.exe
i get the following output:

```
Error loading UIA bridge (UiaDbusBridge, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f4ceacb585d99812): System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'UiaDbusBridge, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f4ceacb585d99812' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'UiaDbusBridge, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f4ceacb585d99812'at System.AppDomain.Load (System.String assemblyString, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, Boolean refonly) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

i also installed the packages:
libmono-uia-*

thx for every help

---

with

MONO_PATH=/usr/lib/uiaatkbridge/ mono fubar.exe

i get:

```
Error loading UIA bridge (UiaDbusBridge, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f4ceacb585d99812): System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'UiaDbusBridge, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f4ceacb585d99812' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'UiaDbusBridge, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f4ceacb585d99812'
  at System.AppDomain.Load (System.String assemblyString, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, Boolean refonly) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.AppDomain.Load (System.String assemblyString) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain:Load (string)
  at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load (System.String assemblyString) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Automation.Provider.BridgeManager.GetAutomationBridge (System.String bridgeAssemblyName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

---

first: thank you for your respons

```
find / | grep uiadbusbridge
```

doesnt give a result, but i think the package issnt named like that...
if i search just for "uia" i get the following result:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libmono-uia-atkbridge1.0-cil.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libmono-uia-winforms1.0-cil.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libmono-uia-winforms1.0-cil.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libmono-uia-atkbridge1.0-cil.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libmono-uia3.0-cil.clilibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libmono-uia-winforms1.0-cil.clilibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libmono-uia-cil-dev.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libmono-uia-cil-dev.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libmono-uia-atkbridge1.0-cil.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libmono-uia3.0-cil.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libmono-uia-atkbridge1.0-cil.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libmono-uia-atkbridge1.0-cil.clilibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libmono-uia3.0-cil.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libmono-uia-atkbridge1.0-cil.shlibs

/usr/lib/uiautomationwinforms
/usr/lib/uiautomationwinforms/UIAutomationWinforms.dll
/usr/lib/uiaatkbridge
/usr/lib/uiaatkbridge/UiaAtkBridge.dll.config
/usr/lib/uiaatkbridge/UiaAtkBridge.dll
/usr/lib/uiaatkbridge/libbridge-glue.so
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/mono-uia.pc
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/amule-adunanza-utils-gui:amuleguiadunanza.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/icons/amuleguiadunanza.png
/usr/share/doc/libmono-uia-winforms1.0-cil
/usr/share/doc/libmono-uia-winforms1.0-cil/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libmono-uia-winforms1.0-cil/NEWS.gz
/usr/share/doc/libmono-uia-winforms1.0-cil/README
/usr/share/doc/libmono-uia-winforms1.0-cil/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libmono-uia-cil-dev
/usr/share/doc/libmono-uia-cil-dev/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libmono-uia-cil-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libmono-uia-atkbridge1.0-cil
/usr/share/doc/libmono-uia-atkbridge1.0-cil/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libmono-uia-atkbridge1.0-cil/NEWS.gz
/usr/share/doc/libmono-uia-atkbridge1.0-cil/README
/usr/share/doc/libmono-uia-atkbridge1.0-cil/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libmono-uia3.0-cil
/usr/share/doc/libmono-uia3.0-cil/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libmono-uia3.0-cil/NEWS.gz
/usr/share/doc/libmono-uia3.0-cil/README
/usr/share/doc/libmono-uia3.0-cil/changelog.Debian.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
MONO_PATH=/usr/lib/uiaatkbridge/ mono fubar.exe
```

Not sure why it wouldn't find the DLL without this though.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, Ubuntu doesn't have the UiaDbusBridge (or the UiaDbus) package. When you search for either of those filenames on the internet, you'll probably stumble upon a website called 'rpmfind' where those files are listed, so they exist somewhere.

There is a github source repository here -> https://github.com/mono/uia2atk/tree/master/UiaDbus

I guess one has to download the stuff and compile it. At least I couldn't find a binary anywhere else on the www.

*edit

okay, the stuff is horibbly outdated (latest commit is from 2 years ago), I fiddled around with it but it's just a mess. Missing references everywhere, using .NET 3.5 and so on.